# Blend UWP flyout tool not staying open

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, blend, flyout

I am currently making a UWP in Blend in Visual Studio 2017 but I am having trouble with the flyout tool. I was hoping to manually control when it opens and when it closes essentially disabling the feature when it closes by itself when it loses focus so that I may be able to interact with other tools or objects in the app before closing the flyout. I have tried adding some C# codes to attempt this but I have had no success. I'm not sure either if this would need to be altered in the template or if it can be done from XAML or preferably C#. I have attached the flyout to a stackpanel and added a button click event in a separate location with the following code:

```
flyout.AllowFocusOnInteraction = true;
flyout.AllowFocusWhenDisabled = true;
flyout.ShowAt(stackpanel);
```

I was hoping this would work to keep the flyout open but it doesn't. I have another button that I had in mind to close it with the following C# code:

```
flyout.Hide();
```

But it would seem that it is not necessary because it closes automatically still regardless of the code. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If the answer has helped you and solve your problem please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer as accepted.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> Represents a control that displays lightweight UI that is either information, or requires user interaction. Unlike a dialog, a [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout) can be light dismissed by clicking or tapping outside of it, pressing the device’s back button, or pressing the ‘Esc’ key.

For your scenario, the `Flyout` control is not reasonable choice. You could achieve this by using [`ContentDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog). And the following code realizes the feature of contentDialog.

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="AppUIBasics.ControlPages.ContentDialogExample"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppUIBasics.ControlPages"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="SIGN IN"
PrimaryButtonText="sign in"
SecondaryButtonText="cancel"
PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<TextBox Name="userNameTextBox" Header="User name"/>
<PasswordBox Name="passwordTextBox" Header="Password" IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True"/>
<CheckBox Name="saveUserNameCheckBox" Content="Save user name"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="errorTextBlock" />
<TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

This the official [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics) about UWP UI basic that you can refer to. If you insist on using Flyout contorl. You could refer to [my code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/KeepFlyoutTest.git). However it is not suggested by the official.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Button Content="Show Flyout">
     <Button.Flyout>
         <Flyout  x:Name="flyout" Closing="flyout_Closing"  >
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="You can edit this text by tapping it."/>
                 <Button Content="close" Click="Button_Click"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </Flyout>
     </Button.Flyout>
 </Button>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private bool manual = false;

 private void flyout_Closing(FlyoutBase sender, FlyoutBaseClosingEventArgs args)
 {
     if(manual == true)
     {
         args.Cancel = false;
     }
     else
     {
         args.Cancel = true;

     }
     manual = false;
 }

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     manual = true;
     flyout.Hide();
 }
```